# There are multiple 'emp_id &emp_name same' recrords, and I just want to retrieve the 'dpt_id null' record, how do I do that?

Tags: postgresql

[This is image Records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CoScU.png)

Records that do not have a dpt_id are in the 'employee' table and those that have dpt_id are in the 'department' table
What if there is emp_id in the two tables, and the output record from the following two tables has contents. I just want to choose which one from the 'employee' table will make the colum 'dpt_id' null

Answer or help for my problems

Comment: As per the [ask], please [**do not** post images of code, data, error message, etc](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551). Instead, copy or type the text into your question, [formatted as code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361#251362). Reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs; things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: `select distinct on (emp_id) * from <your_table> order by emp_id, dept_id nulls first`

Comment: @MikeOrganek it's work the way you give the code. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try the below-modified query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (e.emp_id) e.emp_id, e.emp_name, d.dpt_id
FROM employee e
LEFT JOIN department d ON e.emp_id = d.emp_id
ORDER BY e.emp_id, d.dpt_id NULLS FIRST
```

kindly replace employee and department with your actual table names and adjust column names as needed.